# Detect a clik and start a "function" on CSS

Tags: css, animation, button, click, elementor

Now I have a code that makes a button not visible, and show it in x seconds, my idea was to start this timer, when a video is clicked, I don't need, that if they stop the video, the timer stops, but if it is possible to do it, it would be helpful. I can give, to this video, a name for the ID, and a name for the class, I already did that with the button, and give the name "button".
The code that I alredy have:

```css
body.page-id-2090 #button{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#button {
  animation: show 0s both;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
@keyframes show {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example

Answer (score 0):

There is a few examples to try:

#### CSS selectors:

1. ```
   #element_id:active
   ```

example:

```css
.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  color: red;
}

.button:active {
  margin: 1px 1px 0;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#btnClick {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnClick" />
<label class="button" for="btnClick">Check onClick CSS effect</label>
```

2. ```
   #element_id:target
   ```

example:

```css
#elementToShow {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

#elementToShow:target {
  display: block;
}

.element {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="#elementToShow">Click to show element by CSS selector</a>
<div class="element" id="elementToShow">Element visible!</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, I wanted to have a function to detect when the video is playing or is stopped, and with this information start and pause the timer, I have been searching, and it might be complicated, because you need to know when the video is pressed or isn't, but thanks anyways.

Comment: So in this case it connect to JS/ DOM events, why not solve it quickly by vanilla JS? Is there any case that's forbiden to apply JS?

Comment: I could try JS, I don't know if its gona work, but I could try it.

Comment: It's way easier to do it even by Vanilla JS but if You can use jQuery, will be faster by the $ selector